# How to generate CRUD repository class from entity class spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am coding a Spring boot project. I want to generate repository classes which extends CrudRepository <T, ID>. I have generated entity from tables by JPA tool of Eclipse. Now I have all the entities I need to connect to the MySql Database. Creating repository classes is boring and time consuming because it does not require high coding skills and programming skills. I want to find a quick way to generate Repository classes (as mentioned above) with any possible tool. Looking forward to your help! Thank you very much!

- These are the entity classes I've generated

[image]

- This is the repository class I want to create:
  [image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the required parts of code to the question description to provide minimal reproducible example, that will help future readers for quicker understanding of your issue. Place the code between ``` .... code ```

Comment: You don't usually create a repository for *every* entity, and it's not time consuming to create one. You have a design flaw. Why don't you create the repository when you need it, that way you won't create unnecessary repositories and you don't need to worry about finding a tool you don't need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool you are looking for (actually a run time library), it is the only tool I came across so far **Spring Data Generator**
https://github.com/cmeza20/spring-data-generator

It generates the interfaces automatically, but you need to write some configurations via annotations.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Sorry because I can't vote you up( my reputation is 11). It is very useful. I really really really thank you. Have a good day.

Comment: Spring roo can also do the much stuff(creating model and repos automatically from DB) and EWA is also a tool to do so.